# Can anyone explain me the code and what is been returned in $discountData : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, discount, coupon

```
    $rulePercent = min(100, $rule->getDiscountAmount());
    $discountData = $this->discountFactory->create();

    $itemPrice = $this->validator->getItemPrice($item);
    $baseItemPrice = $this->validator->getItemBasePrice($item);
    $itemOriginalPrice = $this->validator->getItemOriginalPrice($item);
    $baseItemOriginalPrice = $this->validator->getItemBaseOriginalPrice($item);

    $_rulePct = $rulePercent / 100;

    $taxAmount = $itemPrice - ($itemPrice / ((100 + $item->getTaxPercent())/100));
    $perItemTaxAmount = $taxAmount;
    $itemPriceBeforeTax = $itemPrice - $perItemTaxAmount;
    $discountData->setAmount(($qty * $itemPriceBeforeTax - $item->getDiscountAmount()) * $_rulePct);
    $discountData->setBaseAmount(($qty * ($baseItemPrice - $perItemTaxAmount) - $item->getBaseDiscountAmount()) * $_rulePct);
    $discountData->setOriginalAmount(($qty * ($itemOriginalPrice - $perItemTaxAmount) - $item->getDiscountAmount()) * $_rulePct);
    $discountData->setBaseOriginalAmount(
        ($qty * $baseItemOriginalPrice - $item->getBaseDiscountAmount()) * $_rulePct
    );

    if (!$rule->getDiscountQty() || $rule->getDiscountQty() > $qty) {
        $discountPercent = min(100, $item->getDiscountPercent() + $rulePercent);
        $item->setDiscountPercent($discountPercent);
    }

    return $discountData;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the setter functions name suggests the `$discountData` variable contains Amount, Base Amount, Original Amount, Base Original Amount for discount calculation based on the rule (described below).

```
//setting amount
$discountData->setAmount(($qty * $itemPriceBeforeTax - $item->getDiscountAmount()) * $_rulePct);

//setting base amount
$discountData->setBaseAmount(($qty * ($baseItemPrice - $perItemTaxAmount) - $item->getBaseDiscountAmount()) * $_rulePct);

//setting original amount
$discountData->setOriginalAmount(($qty * ($itemOriginalPrice - $perItemTaxAmount) - $item->getDiscountAmount()) * $_rulePct);

//setting base original amount 
$discountData->setBaseOriginalAmount(
        ($qty * $baseItemOriginalPrice - $item->getBaseDiscountAmount()) * $_rulePct
    );
```

Below is the description

**Amount:** The value in the selected store currency for the product.

**Base Amount:** (actually any field that starts with base_) is the value in the default store currency for the product.

**Original Amount:** Excludes discounts, no currency conversion, may or may not include tax.

**Original Base Amount:** Excludes discounts, no currency conversion, may or may not include tax in the default store currency for the product.

If you have only one currency on your website then base_X and X should always have the same value.

**Hope it helps!**

Comment: Can you tell me the difference between the four?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please have a review.

Comment: when we return $discountData does it return item price or the amount that has to be discounted from the original price?

Comment: it'll be returned the discounted amount for the item.